# How can I make a 2x2 piston door that is flush with both the inside and outside walls with no visible redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've been trying to figure out how to create a 2x2 piston door that is flush with the wall on both sides and has no visible redstone (from either side of the door at any point). This would preferably be activated with a button toggle from either side and work ideally in vanilla Minecraft 1.7.10. I have not managed to figure this out myself so I thought I would ask here. My assumption is it would need to have the pistons be powered from below but I'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: So you mean you have a 1 block thick wall that is visible on both sides (not a tunnel) and want no circuit relevant blocks to be seen? Then the only possible space for the circuit is below the floor and you need all kinds of crazy redstone, including two double-piston-extenders side-by-side which both also act as single extenders which get an additional block delivered to them/taken away. This is kind of on the edge of what a question here is for, you're mainly meant to ask about problems you encounter while doing projects yourself. I won't vote to close, because there might also be an easy...

Comment: ... solution and because I have an idea that I want to post once I have access to Minecraft again in ~2 weeks. I'll write an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Sound's like you're asking about a hipster door, [seen in this video by Reversed Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGUEiIQdEtI). The idea of these is that everything is flush with a 1 wide wall, where all the restone is beneath the floor. This design is showcased as 1-wide, but it can be expanded infinitely due to its tileable nature

As far as I can tell, this is the most recent and compact design, but feel free to correct me.

**Edit**:

As per Fabian's request, here's a screenshot with a slightly modified design so it's 1.15 compatible:

[image: Screenshot]

Two things to note:

- The red arrows on the blocks are a tweak from a texture pack, they are observers with the arrows telling you which direction they should be facing. The same with the sticky pistons
- The observer facing down on the bottom left has a piece of redstone dust on it, this is a modification of the original design because of a change that stopped powered blocks from updating observers

Comment: A screenshot would help. That video might disappear any moment and web.archive.org doesn't deal very well with YouTube, so archiving it is also likely not possible (also, copyright).

Comment: @FabianRöling updated with screenshot

Comment: This is good but if possible I was hoping for one compatible with 1.7.10 as that's the version I play the most

Comment: Ah, sorry that version isn't quite my expertise

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This …

- is a 2×2 door
- is flush with a 1 wide wall and the floor
- has no visible redstone (if the floor and walls are actually opaque, the glass is just here for demonstration)
- can be activated by either one of four pressure plates (and can very easily be extended to any other input)
- works in Minecraft 1.7.10, 20w18a, 1.15.2 and probably even 1.0
- has a 0 tick opening phase and a 0 tick closing phase, both starting instantly when the input turns on/off

The only issue is that you are very limited in the selection of blocks for the door. Only actual doors work properly. Alternatively, you could also use fence gates on the lower two blocks and air on the upper two, but then the door does not protect e.g. against skeletons shooting at you through it.

Also, I wouldn't really call this a "**piston** door", but that's just a minor detail. ;)